# How to compare first to second half of measurements in a counterbalanced behavioral experiment?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, manova, counterbalancing

I want to compare measurements in two halves of a behavioral experiment to examine for learning effects. My first course of action is to split the measurements in the two halves and then repeat the original MANOVA for this comparison.

I am asking to find out if there are standard procedures to conduct such a comparison. Or if there are known pitfalls to avoid in such a comparison.

I usually work in R.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about the response variable and the experimental design? What are the other treatments? If you can provide a few lines of R code that produce an example dataset with the right structure, you're more likely to get some answers.